# AngularJS Directive functions not working inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive

I´m doing an Ionic app and created my first directive on it.

The directive is correctly loaded, but from the template (HTML) It can´t execute any function on the directive controller.

**crud_input_fields.html**

```
{{a()}}
```

**crud_input_fields.js**

```
  myapp.directive('crudInputFields', function (fieldService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/Content/Mobile/templates/directives/crud/crud_input_fields.html',
        scope: {
            displayables: '='
        },

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = 'crud_input_fields';
            scope.a = function () {
                console.log('ok');
            }

        },

        controller: function ($scope) {

            $scope.a = function () {
                console.log('ok');
            }

            this.a = function() {
                console.log('ok');
            }




        }
    }
});
```

However, if I put the a function on the `ui-router` Controller, it works fine:

```
 myapp.controller('CrudInputController', function ($log, $scope, crudContextService,fieldService, schemaService, offlineSchemaService, statuscolorService) {





    $scope.a= function () {
        console.log('this works!')
    }     

}
);
```

This controller simply manages a page that, in turns, create calls the directive:

```
<ion-view title="{{title()}}">

    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button-icon icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-content has-header="true">
        <crud-input-fields displayables="displayables"></crud-input-fields>
    </ion-content>


</ion-view>
```

The directive code:

```
    <fieldset ng-repeat="field in displayables">

    {{a()}}
   </fieldset>
```

I´ve put all these different options (this, link, controller), just to test.

The app is ran using Ionic and Ripple and Angular 1.3.15.

Anyone has got a clue?

Comment: PS: link function is called just fine.

It just seems that, for some reason, the directive link and controller functions are not receiving the same $scope object as the the one on the controller.. 

the html, is still looking at the "controller" $scope, and only recognizes its functions

Comment: Just realized now that, removing the scope restriction it works:

 scope: {
        displayables: '='
    },

But as far as I´m concerned, I could make use of it...

Answer (score 2):

---

Your directive controller should be passed to your link function like so:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs,myDirCtrl)
```

NOTE: `myDirCtrl` is an arbitrary name, it could be called anything

---

then you call your directive controller function inside the link function like so:

```
scope.a = function () {
        myDirCtrl.a();
    }
```

---

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/E4Mv6f?p=preview) that proves the point

Comment: If I do it exactly like that, the $scope is not even defined...

It needed to be scope.a, isnt?

But no luck either

Comment: myDirCtrl.a(), would, indeed work on the link function.

But the original problem remains:

I.e the template code can´t access it.

Comment: yes, define a template in your directive for a test: '<div><div ng-click="a()">test me</div></div>'

Comment: helped,but not yet "worked".

Do you know why it wouldn´t work on the templateUrl? I want to use the url, not to declare a big html here

Comment: oh yes, if you put the same kind of input inside a templateUrl, it would work as well

Comment: usually when you call a directive scope function, it's on an event like ng-click, ng-change, etc...

Comment: Getting close, due to your tip:

The problem seems to be not the html itself, but the presence of a ng-repeat on it.

Inside the ng-repeat it´s not yet working.

Comment: could you provide a plunker? or I could make one, then you input your code, and we'll figure it out...

Comment: edited the question to make it more meaningful (hopefully) to others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78643/discussion-between-luiz-rolim-and-manube).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was due to the way the html was declared:

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="field in displayables" ng-show="!isFieldHidden(field)">

        {{a()}}
</fieldset>
```

Didn´t work.

However,

```
 <fieldset ng-repeat="field in getDisplayables()" ng-show="!isFieldHidden(field)">

            {{a()}}
    </fieldset>
```

worked, where getDisplayables() fn would just return the displayables:

```
  $scope.getDisplayables= function() {
                return $scope.displayables;
            }
```

Still don´t know why, though. I do know the ng-repeat create child scopes, but this scenario is kinda subtle, isn´t?

Comment: are you still interested in knowing why it did not work as you expected?

Comment: sure, always good to understaand things! Do you need any extra details?

Comment: well, the best would be to fill up the plunker I provided with your original code; what I think is you are passing data to your directive (displayables); you should set a $watch on that data in the link func like so: scope.$watch('displayables', function(data){scope.displayables=data;});

Comment: the $watch executes when the data (displayables) has been passed to the directive (when it's ready), then it sets the scope attribute:scope.displayables

Comment: Man, to be honest, like I said, I would love to understaand it deeply, but I need to continue coding some extra stuff here.

However the question is: why would the function on the ng-repeat, (instead of simply the straight array) made the ng-repeat scope to "extend" the directive functions.

Comment: I think it's a question of timing: when you pass data to a directive, it can use it when it's ready (usually you use a $watch to act when your data is ready); when you execute a function inside your ng-repeat it does the same thing: assign the ready data to scope